# angularjs - using 'string' names on the scope or ng-model

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

In normal JavaScript, you can declare variables like this;

```
var obj = {};
obj["item-text"] = {};
obj["item text"] = {};
```

Example given here: http://jsbin.com/petafu/1/edit

And it's perfectly fine. But this doesn't seem to work in angular on the `$scope`. I attempted to do this and could not really understand why, but cannot find any resources talking about it...

## JS

```
app.controller('ControllerName', function($scope){
   $scope['item text'] = {};
   $scope['item-text'] = {};
});
```

## HTML

```
<div ng-model="item text"></div>
<div ng-model="item-text"></div>
```

Comment: I'm not really contesting or upset about the proposed edits to my simple word and capitalization choices, but can I ask the reasoning? Is it because of some sort of standards or search engine compliance? Personal preference? Grammatically irksome?

Comment: Your examples of "normal JavaScript" do not work

Comment: Sorry, just forgot a small part of it - I'm a little absentminded today.

Comment: I didn't write it correctly at first, no. I'm sorry, I just got ahead of myself. But the way I am using variables does indeed work fine; you can see it yourself here: http://jsbin.com/petafu/1/edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want hyphens and spaces I'd probably go with [controller as](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification) syntax.

View:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl as ctrl">
  <p>Hello {{ctrl.name}}!</p>
  <input ng-model="ctrl.name1" />
  <input ng-model="ctrl['name-2']" />
  <input ng-model="ctrl['name 3']" />
</body>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  this.name = 'World';
  this['name1'] = "world1";
  this['name-2'] = "world 2";
  this['name 3'] = "world 3";
});
```

Using your `obj` variable.

Controller:

```
var obj = {};
obj["item-text"] = {};
obj["item text"] = {};
$scope.obj = obj;
```

View:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input ng-model="obj['item text']" />
  <input ng-model="obj['item-text']" />
</body>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/OqTN59Ewsc6ydKnjSGbx?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, that works - but why does it work when done on `this`, but it cannot when done on `$scope`? Is there something special about `$scope`?

Comment: Okay, so you could do it on `$scope`, just not quite how you have it. Set `$scope.obj = obj` as you define it in your question and it should work in the view. I can add another example if that would help.

Comment: So I would simply assign `$scope.obj = obj` and then would put `obj['name-2'] = //..assignment..//` or `obj['name 2'] = //..assignment..//`? That does accomplish what I need for this specific use case, but I'm still not clear why it cannot be done to `$scope` directly. There must be something special about it as an object...

Comment: You could get ride of the `as`. http://plnkr.co/edit/96Mb2dFz5ETwuONXEshT?p=preview

Comment: @Ciel I think a quick read through [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) will help you clear your doubts.

Comment: Wow, yes. That is an extremely useful link. Thank you. I'll keep reading on this. I understand what @AndyGaskell is saying too. I guess I'm just a bit confused that `$scope` gets to act like something special, when I thought that all objects in java script had some fairly base behavior like this.

Comment: Hey, forgive me for my impertinent stupidity, but while this answer tells me how to accomplish my goal, I'm still lost as to why `$scope` cannot have one of these types of objects directly put on it. @akskap, do either of you know the answer to that?

Answer (score 2):

$scope in Angular's context is an **object**. It refers to the application model.

Therefore,

```
$scope.item_text = 'Hello';
```

or

```
$scope['item_text'] = 'Hello';
```

should both work.

However, please take note of **[ng-model](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)** which can be only used on form elements.

With any of the above declarations,

```
<input type="text" ng-model="item_text">
```

will work

Comment: So a dash simply cannot exist in a variable name for any reason? It has to be an underscore?

Answer (score 0):

Try writing like this

```
$scope.itemText={};
```

use should consider using camelcase in javascript as spaces and dashes often causes too many problems

Comment: Well. I'm aware of that, but I would still like to understand it. I have some situations where it is needed, such as third party libraries that don't give me control of the names they expect.