# angular js expressions not working

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I have this lines ofcode in my HTML,

```
<div ng-app='myApp' ng-controller='myCtrl'>
    <h5 style="margin: 0;">As of {{ date-today }}</h5>
</div>
```

In my JS,

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$compile', '$http', function($scope, $compile, $http){
    var today = new Date();
    $scope.date_today = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
    initTables($scope, $compile);
}
```

It is not working. It displays {{ }}.

Comment: You have a typo in your variable name.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs - using 'string' names on the scope or ng-model](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25043148/angularjs-using-string-names-on-the-scope-or-ng-model)

Comment: `date_today` !== `date-today`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change "date-today"
to "date_today"  like in the $scope.

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $compile, $http){
    var today = new Date();
    $scope.date_today = today.getFullYear()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getDate();
    //initTables($scope, $compile);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{date_today}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Seems to work fine to me make sure you have date_today in both places in JS it's going to see the - as a minus and not parse it you should have had a syntax error I believe (with $scope.date-today, $scope['date-today'] may have worked but still not ideal IMO).