# Angularjs - ng-disabled doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to disable file `input` tag, after user selected a file.

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller='firstController'>
    <div ng-controller='secondController'>
      <input type="file" name="file" upload class="theFileInput" ng-disabled="fileInMemory">
    </div>
</div>
```

JS, first controller:

```
$scope.fileInMemory = false; // tracks if user selected a file for upload, but didn't upload it
$rootScope.$on('fileAdded', function () {
     $scope.fileInMemory = true;
     console.log($scope.fileInMemory);
});
```

`upload` is a directive.

On page load, `ng-disabled` has `false` as it should, when `fileInMemory` is changed, `input` tag still not being disabled. `console.log` shows that the value of `fileInMemory` is changing as it should.

**What i tried so far**

```
<input type="file" name="file" class="theFileInput" ng-disabled="'fileInMemory'">
```

Just disables the field right away, when `fileInMemory` is falsy.

```
<input type="file" name="file" class="theFileInput" ng-disabled="fileInMemory == 'true'">
```

Doesn't work.

```
<input type="file" name="file" class="theFileInput" ng-disabled="{{fileInMemory}}">
```

Still doesn't work.

What is the best way to disable an `input` tag?

**Found the issue**

It looks like the issue here is scopes. 
I have `firstController` with its' scope, inside it `secondController` with its' scope, and on the `input` tag `upload` directive, which apparently creates its' own scope and doesn't see `firstController` scope.

`secondController` and `upload` are general controllers and therefore don't inherit from `firstController`.

I guess my best solution is to add some general handler in `secondController`, which based on additional attribute on `input` field will disable the it when needed.

Comment: don't use an expression, just the variable

Comment: I think the file input is not in the scope that fileInMemory  belong to. Can you make a demo?

Comment: @charlietfl i used the variable as well, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Alborz how can i check if they are in the same scope? when i output the value of `fileInMemory` to the HTML, it shows properly, with correct value.

Comment: are there any child scopes involved? Might be better if you use an object with `fileInMemory` as property if there are child scopes

Comment: Do you use a nested scope? use abject instead of primitive type.

Comment: @Alborz yep, nested scope issue, indeed. ty, helped me figure out whats wrong ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're going to have to leverage `$apply` here because it's being changed inside of the event:

```
$scope.fileInMemory = false;
$rootScope.$on('fileAdded', function () {
    $scope.$apply(function() {
        $scope.fileInMemory = true;
        console.log($scope.fileInMemory);
    });
});
```

**UPDATE:** in response to an isolated-scope causing issues, move `fileInMemory` to the `$rootScope`:

```
$rootScope.fileInMemory = false;
$rootScope.$on('fileAdded', function () {
    $rootScope.$apply(function() {
        $rootScope.fileInMemory = true;
        console.log($scope.fileInMemory);
    });
});
```

Comment: i tried it with `$scope.$apply` but it still doesn't work. I think that `directive` on the element creates its own isolated scope.

Comment: @Neara, the fix there would be to move the variable to the `$rootScope` instead of `$scope`.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is with scopes, try using "controller as" syntax:

```
<div ng-controller='firstController as first'>
    <div ng-controller='secondController as second'>
      <input type="file" name="file" upload class="theFileInput" ng-disabled="first.fileInMemory">
    </div>
</div>
```

Link:
[AngularJs "controller as" syntax - clarification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification)

Answer (score 1):

did you tried like this

```
<input type="file" name="file" class="theFileInput" ng-disabled="fileInMemory">
```

here is a working example [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Mh3qWSG3KTyQwETJTlqx?p=preview)

Comment: i have posted demo link, can you share your code ? may be the value is not in right scope ?

Comment: i added more code, i do have one controller inside another, and the variable is being manipulated by outer controller. is it an issue?

Comment: yes, if you have nested controllers you should use controller name before variable for example ctrl2.fileInMemory

Answer (score 1):

Briefly, each `ngController` creates a new child scope. The scope created by `secondController` shadows the value of `fileInMemory` from `firstController`. Because of this, the change doesn't propagate and its value is *locked* to `false`. This can easily be avoided by using `controllerAs` syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Try following

```
ng-disabled="fileInMemory"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use abject instead of primitive type.

In the first controller:

```
$scope.model = {};
$scope.model.fileInMemory = false; 
$rootScope.$on('fileAdded', function () {
        $scope.model.fileInMemory = true;
        console.log($scope.model.fileInMemory);
    });
```

---

```
<div ng-controller='firstController'>
    <div ng-controller='secondController'>
      <input type="file" name="file" class="theFileInput" ng-disabled="model.fileInMemory">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i tried this, it still doesn't work. I also tried referencing by controller first: `firstController.model.fileInMemory`.

Comment: post a demo if it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

did you try this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller='firstController'>
    <div ng-controller='secondController'>
      <input type="file" name="file" upload class="theFileInput" ng-disabled="fileInMemory.disabled">
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.fileInMemory = { disabled: false }; 

$rootScope.$on('fileAdded', function () {
     $scope.fileInMemory.disabled = true;
     console.log($scope.fileInMemory);
});
```

[Working fiddle here](https://fiddle.jshell.net/ergwkywL/)

Answer (score -1):

Your model is being changed on the console but not in views because this change is happening outside of angular app. The way to fix it is to call $apply on $rootScope to ensure that the views are updated of this event being called from outside angular app scope.

```
// Something like this
$rootScope.$apply(function() {
  $rootScope.fileInMemory = true;
  // Now it'll be changed in views too
});
```