# Why alias is used for ng-controller in Angular?

Tags: angularjs, controller, alias

```
ng-controller="StoreController as store"
```

instead of

```
ng-controller="StoreController"
```

What is the difference?

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification) as to know why they add an alias or specifically a scope for Angular. It's more of a `clearer namespaces` vs `confusing namespaces`

Answer (score 1):

Additionally, an alias is **like an instance in POO**. By doing this you are sure to be accessing only the StoreController scope in you code.

You can get *controllers(child)* which are shadowed in another *controller(parent)* with the same scope '*id*'. Doing this *{{ id }}* will display the id of the parent.

Using an alias this becomes

```
controllers(child) as child
controller(parent) as parent
```

and 
*child.id gives the id of the child* and
*parent.id displays the id of the parent.*

Hope this helps