# What is the difference between controller and controllerAs in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new in AngularJS, I am confused in term 'controller' and 'controller As'.
Why we use both at a time? I want brief description about this both directives?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angularjs "Controller as" or "$scope"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30641478/angularjs-controller-as-or-scope)

Comment: you may find relevant solution on https://toddmotto.com/digging-into-angulars-controller-as-syntax/

Comment: Related: [What can be the reason to use "controllerAs" property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31838265/what-can-be-the-reason-to-use-controlleras-property)

Answer (score 3):

Both things, **controller** and **controllerAs** refer to the same thing - the controller you want to work with in the specific view. They differ in the way you are going to access the properties and functions inside it. The **controllerAs** syntax is optional, but I highly recommend it.

**Edit:** controllerAs is an alias for the controller that you specify, and slightly modifies the way you approach values within the controller

If you don't specify **controllerAs** you will work with *$scope* inside the controller, and you will directly access the properties and functions from the scope of the controller, which, more or less, is a bad practice. For example:

In controller:

```
$scope.employer = 'John';
$scope.totalEmployees = 15;
```

In view:

```
<div>{{employer}} has {{totalEmployees}} employees</div>
```

**Note**: see how the view accesses the values directly from the *scope*.

However, if you specify **controllerAs**

controller: 'EmployeeController'

controllerAs: 'emp';

The approach is a little bit different, yet cleaner and easier to maintain:

In controller:

```
var emp = this;
emp.employer = 'John';
emp.totalEmployees = 15;
```

In view:

```
<div>{{emp.employer}} has {{emp.totalEmloyees} employees}}</div>
```

**Note:** Now you have to specify the alias in the view in order to access the values. This is a good practice, because as the application grows, the complexity grows as well. With **controllerAs** you have more control over you application and it is easier to maintain and debug.

Answer (score 1):

Inside controller directive of your html you can access the values assigned to your `$scope` variable, But if you use controllerAs = "vm" syntax;

You may simply (in your controller) do:

```
var vm = this;
vm.myModel = 'my model text'
```

So you don't need to assign values to $scope and in your html you can access it

```
<div>{{vm.myModel}}</div>
```

Comment: You can also check this detailed answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers?rq=1