# Angular js Not Returning any thing on Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a simple Angular js script like below it is not returning any thing in page and also no error on console

the `index.html` is like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <title>Angular Starting</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.4/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  <div ng-controller="MovieStore as store">
      <h1 {{store.item.name}}></h1>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and the `app.js` is like

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MovieStore', function(){
        this.item = movies;
     });

    var movies ={
        name :'Cinema Paradiso',
        price: 333,
    }
})();
```

can you please let me know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Is the Angular expression actually inside the `h1` tag? It probably shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div ng-controller="MovieStore as store">
   <h1> {{store.item.name}}></h1>
</div>

(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MovieStore', function($scope){
        var movies ={
          name :'Cinema Paradiso',
          price: 333,
        };
        $scope.item = movies;
     });

})();
```

Comment: Hi Kushal, can you please let me know why you used `$scope` instead of `this`

Comment: Dependency injection is the most important feature in angularjs and as for the "this" sometimes the function may not run in the context that you were expecting it to run in angular .. so to make sure your code always work in the controllers scope .. $scope is injected and used accordingly

Comment: Thanks but after using the `$scope`  agian not getting any thing on the page ! it was working with `this`, however (after correcting the `<h1> {{store.item.name}}></h1>`) !

Comment: Try it this way then <div ng-controller="MovieStore">
   <h1> {{item.name}}></h1>
</div>

Comment: yeah it works now but does this mean we do not need store allies in `<div ng-controller="MovieStore as store">` any more?

Comment: Aliases as supported in latest angularjs only .. if its available in yours then it should have worked

Answer (score 1):

you need to assign value in scope so change your app.js to :

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MovieStore', function(){
        var movies = {
            name :'Cinema Paradiso',
            price: 333,
        }
        this.item = movies;
     });
})();
```

correct your html by changing

```
<h1 {{store.item.name}}></h1>
```

to

```
<h1> {{store.item.name}}></h1>
```

Comment: Hi Jugnu, can you please let me know why you used `$scope` instead of `this` ?

Comment: $scope is an object that refers to the application model.We need to insert dependency for $scope service inside controller and assign value to scope and  these scope values will be available in html snippet having that controller.

Comment: have a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope hope so it will clear your concept about scope.

Comment: Thanks but after using the `$scope`  again not getting any thing on the page ! it was working with `this`, however (after correcting the `<h1> {{store.item.name}}></h1>`) !

Comment: it must be working with $scope but you might have done <h1 {{store.item.name}}></h1> like this so it will be assigned as attribute to  h1 tag instead of h1 content. you can see by inspecting element.

Comment: yes one more point this work with controller alias so store.item.name will work with MovieStore as store, for using $scope remove alias for controller. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification

Answer (score 0):

I believe that with AngularJS, you need to have something "serve the page up" if you are trying to launch the page locally on your machine.

I use a nifty code editor [brackets.io](http://brackets.io/) that does this automatically for me.

and also the `h1` tag should probably be `<h1>{{store.item.name}}</h1>`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-controller="MovieStore">
   <h1> {{item.name}}></h1>
</div>

(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MovieStore', function(){
        var movies ={
          name :'Cinema Paradiso',
          price: 333,
        };
        this.item = movies;
     });

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

In your app.js file write

```
(function(){
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('MovieStore', function(){
        var item=this; //please write this line and check it
        this.item = movies;
     });

var movies ={
    name :'Cinema Paradiso',
    price: 333,
}
```

})();