# Having "as ctrl" in ng-controller versus not having it

Tags: angularjs, angular-controller

I am pretty new to angular materials. I am trying to use the autocomplete feature.

I have some autocomplete sample code here;
http://codepen.io/helpme/pen/KzxXPQ

The first thing that stumped me is this declaration of the controller;

```
<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl as ctrl" layout="column" ng-cloak="" ng-app="MyApp">
```

In my past angularjs code, the ng-controller is declared this way `<div ng-controller="DemoCtrl"` without the `as ctrl`.

What is the difference between having `as ctrl` and not having it? How should the code at http://codepen.io/helpme/pen/KzxXPQ be changed if the `as ctrl` is removed?

Comment: this is clarified here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification

Comment: You can read more about `as ctrl` [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController). If you don't want use `as ctrl`, remove it in html and in controller remove `var self = this` and change `self` to `$scope` (Don't forget put $scope in controller).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

John Papa's excellent [Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#controllers) (essential reading for all new Angular devs IMO) covers this rather well:

> Why?: Controllers are constructed, "newed" up, and provide a single new instance, and the controllerAs syntax is closer to that of a JavaScript constructor than the classic $scope syntax.
>
> Why?: It promotes the use of binding to a "dotted" object in the View (e.g. customer.name instead of name), which is more contextual, easier to read, and avoids any reference issues that may occur without "dotting".
>
> Why?: Helps avoid using $parent calls in Views with nested controllers.

Points 2 and 3 are the key for me - it makes your code a lot easier to read and maintain.