# Why should I use controllerAs syntax

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Should I use `controllerAs` syntax defining `$scope` or use `vm` in angular js controller? I saw people using `controllerAs` syntax and `$scope`.
What is the difference between them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see related [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification)

they both define variables in $scope