# In Angular 1 when is it optimal to use controllers with "as" syntax?

Tags: angularjs, controller

I just started to wrap my head around controllers, however in a tutorial for learning ui-router I saw my presenter using his controller with "as" syntax. I researched more about it and saw it instantiates a controller as a class.

When should "as" syntax be used?

Comment: This looks like a good resource: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification

Answer (score 0):

situation 1:-
Many times we use directives in our view. Directives may have used scope object inside it. now we have two scope object one of controller's and other of directive's.

situation 2: 
When we two controllers in same html file we need to have mapping of variable then we need that syntax(not recomanded)

Answer (score 0):

using either:

```
controller: 'MyController as MyCtrl'
```

or

```
controller: 'MyController',
controllerAs: 'MyCtrl'
```

simply exposes the controller object on scope.  This lets you access its properties/methods directly from your template (ex. `{{MyCtrl.foo}}` or `ng-click="MyCtrl.doStuff()"`) or inheriting scopes.