# Content is not showing using angular.js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
<html ng-app = "sampleMod">
    <head>

    </head>

    <body ng-controller = "sampleCon">
        <script src = "bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
        <h1>Filters example</h1>
        Comments (upper) :- <input type = "text" ng-model = "sampleCon.upper"><br>
        {{sampleCon.upper | uppercase}}<br>
        Comments (lower) :- <input type = "text" ng-model = "sampleCon.lower"><br>
        {{sampleCon.lower | lowercase}}<br>
        <button type = "button">Name</button>
        <button type = "button">Age</button>
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat = "person in sampleCon.array1">
                    <b>Name</b> - {{person.name}}<br>
                    <b>Age</b> - {{person.age}}<br><br>
                </li>
            <ul>
        </div>

        <script>
            app = angular.module("sampleMod",[]);
            app.controller("sampleCon",function(){
                this.upper = "";
                this.lower = "";
                this.array1 = [{name:"sahib",
                              age:17},
                              {name:"kukku",
                              age:25},
                              {name:"meena",
                              age:45},
                              {name:"ayaan",
                              age:2},
                             ]
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I made a web page using angular js ,everything seems to work fine but the content having the ng-repeat directive was not visible on the screen .I am not able to detect any error the above program

Comment: when you mark answer give priority for the ones who answers fast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `sampleCon` everywhere in your HTML except in `ng-controller = "sampleCon"`

`sampleCon.upper` to `upper`
`sampleCon.lower` to `lower`
`sampleCon.array1` to `array1`

Or just do `ng-controller = "sampleCon as sampleCon"`

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) variable instead of this,

```
$scope.upper = "";
$scope.lower = "";
$scope.array1 = [{name:"sahib",
                              age:17},
                              {name:"kukku",
                              age:25},
                              {name:"meena",
                              age:45},
                              {name:"ayaan",
                              age:2},
                             ]
```

and HTML should be,

```
 <h1>Filters example</h1>
        Comments (upper) :- <input type = "text" ng-model = "upper"><br>
        {{upper | uppercase}}<br>
        Comments (lower) :- <input type = "text" ng-model = "lower"><br>
        {{lower | lowercase}}<br>
  <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat = "person in array1">
                <b>Name</b> - {{person.name}}<br>
                <b>Age</b> - {{person.age}}<br><br>
            </li>
        <ul>
    </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/T7NZilD2DcJ96PVLtvQQ?p=preview)**

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
<li ng-repeat = "person in sampleCon.array1">
                    <b>Name</b> - {{person.name}}<br>
                    <b>Age</b> - {{person.age}}<br><br>
                </li>
```

use

```
<li ng-repeat = "person in array1">
                    <b>Name</b> - {{person.name}}<br>
                    <b>Age</b> - {{person.age}}<br><br>
                </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

As [other answers correctly mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39748238/4949005) you can use `$scope` instead of `this` in your controller. Alternatively you can use the [`controller as`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification)-syntax.

```
</head>

<body ng-controller = "sampleCon as ctrl"> <!-- Name your controller 'ctrl' -->
    <script src = "bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <h1>Filters example</h1>
    Comments (upper) :- <input type = "text" ng-model = "ctrl.upper"><br>
    {{ctrl.upper | uppercase}}<br>
    Comments (lower) :- <input type = "text" ng-model = "ctrl.lower"><br>
    {{ctrl.lower | lowercase}}<br>
    <button type = "button">Name</button>
    <button type = "button">Age</button>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat = "person in ctrl.array1">
                <b>Name</b> - {{person.name}}<br>
                <b>Age</b> - {{person.age}}<br><br>
            </li>
        <ul>
    </div>

    <script>
        app = angular.module("sampleMod",[]);
        app.controller("sampleCon",function(){
            var vm = this;
            vm.upper = "";
            vm.lower = "";
            vm.array1 = [{name:"sahib",
                          age:17},
                          {name:"kukku",
                          age:25},
                          {name:"meena",
                          age:45},
                          {name:"ayaan",
                          age:2},
                         ]
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.controller("sampleCon",function($scope){
     $scope.upper = "";
     $scope.lower = "";
     $scope.array1 = [{name:"sahib",
                        age:17},
                              {name:"kukku",
                              age:25},
                             ]
   });
```

Use the $scope, and html like

```
 <li ng-repeat = "person in array1">
                <b>Name</b> - {{person.name}}<br>
                <b>Age</b> - {{person.age}}<br><br>
            </li>
```