# How to get AngularJS alias controller name?

Tags: angularjs

How to programatically get the **name** from an alias of a AngularJS controllerAs syntax?

```
MyController as mine
```

How I get the `mine` variable?
To be clear, I have `MyController` with multiple usages:

```
MyController as use1
MyController as use2
```

How inside MyController I get the `use1` or the `use2`

Comment: This may help you to understand the syntax- [AngularJs “controller as” syntax - clarification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification)

Comment: I edited my question. It is not a duplicate.

Comment: please read this doc-[Understanding Controllers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller). Especially this point may be helpful for you: _**Share code or state across controllers — Use angular services instead.**_

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to use it

```js
var app = angular.module("myShoppingList", []); 
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    var mine = this; //You can change "mine" with whatever you want
    mine.products = ["Milk", "Bread", "Cheese"];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myShoppingList" ng-controller="myCtrl as mine"> <!--Use the choosen name-->
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in mine.products">{{x}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

An example of "Controller As" syntax that was revealed in Angular JS 1.2.0

```
angular.module('app')
    .controller('Customers', [function() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.title = 'Customers';
      vm.customers = [
        {name: 'Haley'}, {name: 'Ella'}, {name: 'Landon'}, {name: 'John'}
        ];
}]);
```

To use it in view

```
<article ng-controller="Customers as vm">
   <ul ng-repeat="c in vm.customers">
       <li></li>
</ul>
</article>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm using exactly as you described. But there's any way I can get the name of the alias? Like inside the CustomerCtrl I can get "vm" (because vm is defined as the alias). I have a controller reused with different names and I would like to get the as "name"