# Angular JS: placeholders not getting resolved

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My angular js code is not resolving the placeholders ,while I am trying to get it resolved on runtime.

Js code :

```
var message ={s:"hello {{name}}"};

angular.module("myapp",[]).controller("myctrl", function($scope){

  var ctrl=this;

  $scope.name="david";
  $scope.w=message.s;

  $scope.call=function(){
    //alert(message);
  };

});
```

HTML :

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl as ctrl">
        {{w}}
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.name" />
        <input type="submit" ng-click="call();" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Expected output is :hello david;

Attaching fiddle link :https://jsfiddle.net/rakotkar/o46coezd/2/

Comment: You have to use `{{name}}` (interpolation) only in the template

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up  controller as syntax and `$scope`. When you are using controller as syntax , you have to use `this` keyword instead of `$scope`.

**JS**

```
var message ={s:"hello "};

angular.module("myapp",[]).controller("myctrl",function(){

  var ctrl = this;

  ctrl.name ="david";
  ctrl.w = message.s;
  ctrl.call = function(){
    //alert(message);
  };

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="myctrl as ctrl">
        {{ctrl.w}}{{ctrl.name}}
        <input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.name" />
        <input type="submit" ng-click="call();" />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Demo**:https://jsfiddle.net/o46coezd/4/

For more info on controller as syntax:[AngularJs "controller as" syntax - clarification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification)

Comment: It wouldn't help me ,as per my real business scenario, I need to display different messages and I need to populate different attributes in the message.

Comment: What different messages and attributes?

Comment: Tried to explain the same .please refer https://jsfiddle.net/rakotkar/o46coezd/16/

Comment: You can use ctrl.message ={s:"hello"+" "+ ctrl.name }; if thats what you are looking for

Comment: what I want to do is , I want to keep the error messages in a seperate js file so that I can get directly on my page but the messages need the value from response,$scope variables so wanted to take this approach.

Comment: You can simply store the error messages in a scope variable and print it if a flag is true

Comment: so my response would contain different fields , now based on some conditions I need to pick up different messages and those messages need different field of response.

Comment: my messages are something like the application for {{product}} is rejected.and hence need of doing this I feel. and I dont want to do string concatenation.

Comment: You can store the corresponding value of your varaible(product in this case) in a scope variable and show it in the front end. In js if you want you have to do something like this $scope.error="application for" +$scope.product +"is rejected" and print in the UI if  a flag is true by {{error}}

Comment: This spolution was already on my mind but I felt String concatenation would make code look dirty , so tried to avoided that .Thanks for inputs.

Comment: "hello {{name}}" is same as "hello" + $scope.name though the former won't work. So I don't see any difference in logic that would not make  "hello {{name}}" code less dirty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148891/discussion-between-vivz-and-rajeev-akotkar).

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below. As you're trying to access scope from outside module, it's not possible I think.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="myctrl as ctrl">
{{w}}
<input type="text" ng-model="ctrl.name"/>
<input type="submit" ng-click="call();"/>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var message ={s:"hello"};
angular.module("myapp",[]).controller("myctrl", function($scope){

  var ctrl=this;
  $scope.text = message;
  $scope.name="david";
  $scope.w= $scope.text.s + ' ' + $scope.name;

  $scope.call=function(){
    //alert(message);
  };

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it would not help as I am haivng a big message string that requires the place holders in between and these place holders will be resolved once the response comes from the api and then assigned as scope variables.

Comment: than you can keep your "Message" variable inside module right??

Comment: doesnt seem much useful to me.Sorry I misunderstood as if you are asking tohave ngMessage.I wanted to keep message variable in an separate  js fiel and then just put {{}} expression and resolve them on runtime/while rendering .