# adding data-ng-controller disruptive other data-ng properties

Tags: html, angularjs

Hi i am trying to build login form in asp.net environment that using angular to validate the input fields.

the problem is when i add

```
data-ng-controller="loginC"
```

disruptive other data-ng properties for example the user name is indeed valid but 
it still show me an error.

```
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" data-ng-model="class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" vm.username" data-ng-required="true" >
```

and the condition for the span is

```
<span data-ng-show="form.username.$invalid && form.username.$touched" 
class="help-block">Username is required</span>
```

this is the whole code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="beforeLogin" Runat="Server">  
<div class="text-center" style="padding: 50px 0">

    <!-- Main Form -->
    <div class="login-form-1 " style="padding: 1%; border-radius: 10%">
        <div class="logo">Login</div>
        <section class="card register" data-ng-app="Login" data-ng-controller="loginC">
            <form name="form" class="text-left" data-ng-submit="vm.login()">
                <div class="login-form-main-message login-group"></div>
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.username.$invalid && form.username.$touched}">
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="username" data-ng-model="vm.username" data-ng-required="true" />
                        <span data-ng-show="form.username.$invalid && form.username.$touched" class="help-block">Username is required</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group" data-ng-class="{ 'has-error': form.password.$invalid && form.password.$touched }">
                        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" data-ng-model="vm.password" data-ng-required="true" />
                        <span data-ng-show="form.password.$invalid && form.password.$touched" class="help-block">Password is required</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions" style="margin: 0 auto; width: 40%;">
                        <button type="submit" data-ng-disabled="form.$invalid || vm.dataLoading" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                        <a href="Registration.aspx" class="btn btn-link">Register</a>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </section>
    </div>
    <!-- end:Main Form -->
</div>
```

note again when i am remove the data-ng-controller everything work good

Comment: Did you try changing `ng-controller="loginC as vm"`. The `vm` part of the validation logic requires the controller to be named so.

Comment: Also, what is in the controller? Has it already been exported as `vm`?

Comment: you are right i added this and it worked,  but i did not understand your explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AngularJS follows the MV* Pattern. So your view(ie- the html) talks to the application logic through a 'controller'.

When you setup `data-ng-controller`, the view has a reference to it's scope. You can access the controllers values by using `$scope.value` syntax. By default, you can access functions and values of the controller by using the `$scope.value` syntax. But in this example,`vm.value` is used. . Such as - `vm.login()`, `vm.dataLoading`.

This syntax assumes that there is a controller with an alias of `vm`. But the controller is imported without an alias. [This question goes in to more detail about aliases.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification) There for, the view has no reference of the `vm` controller and the `vm.username` value is undefined and doesn't validate.

Using the 'controller as' syntax would would fix the problem with the username. `ng-controller="loginC as vm"`. But you will need to keep consistency when calling methods and accessing values in order for all the functionality to work.

Comment: i got it,  but how  it's  worked  before i wrote the ng-controller command?

Comment: @YonatanAmir Is there by any chance, a controller imported as 'vm' in a parent of this component? If so, that might be the cause for it to work. Or it could be that since a controller was not defined, the functionality didn't work at all. Failing without giving an error.