# angularjs model value is undefined in form

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two forms(in one page). On first form there are two buttons NEXT and BACK. On clicking on the next i will render next form on page. I am using ng-if for this condition.

```
<form name="otpform" novalidate ng-if="renderotpform">
  <fieldset ng-disabled="otpdisable">
    <div class="middle-container steps fourth-step overflow-hidden" id="divotp">
      <input class="" type="text" name="otp" placeholder="{{ 'OTP' | translate }}" ng-model="otp" required >
      <input type="button" value="{{ 'BACK' | translate }}" class="brown-button" ng-click="gotoAck()">
      <input type="submit" value="{{ 'NEXT' | translate }}" class="blue-button" ng-click="checkotp()">
    </div>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Below is my js code.

```
 $scope.checkotp = function () {
                debugger;
                var otpvalue;
                $scope.otp = {};
                otpvalue = $scope.otp; //undefined
              }
```

When I try to access the otp model I am getting undefined property. On previous form I have next button. Inside next button I have   `$scope.renderotpform = true;` so that above form is shown. May I know why I am not able to access OTP in the above code?

Comment: why you are doing this? $scope.otp = {}; It will assign otp value to black object.

Comment: Thank you. I removed $scope.otp={} and still i am getting undefined.

Comment: Its will be undefine untill you enter any value to text box;

Comment: i have entered some value. I have checkotp() function. On clicking on that i am checking the value. Hope you understood.

Comment: Then please create fiddle to see whole code, that must be something making otp blanck

Comment: i removed ng-if="renderotpform" and started working fine. may i know what is wrong with my ng-if?

Comment: When your renderotpform will be false or undefined , it will not load form in which otp textbox exist. so that will not assign $scope.otp to any value or infact it will not populate $scope.otp.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150923/discussion-between-niranjan-godbole-and-jenny).

Comment: one can make use of `ng-show` instead of `ng-if` as the latter removes the content from the DOM itself, whereas the former just hides it, when the condition becomes _false_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-if` creates its own scope. So the otp inside `ng-if` is not binded directly to the controller.You can either bind the model to an object or use **controller as** syntax. The **controller as** syntax implicitly takes care of the dot rule.

**For more info**:

1. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes
2. [AngularJs "controller as" syntax - clarification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification)

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  var vm=this;
  vm.renderotpform = true;
  vm.checkotp = function() {
    console.log(vm.otp);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <form name="otpform" novalidate ng-if="vm.renderotpform">
      <fieldset ng-disabled="otpdisable">
        <div class="middle-container steps fourth-step overflow-hidden" id="divotp">
          <input class="" type="text" name="otp"  ng-model="vm.otp" required>
          <input type="button" value="BACK" class="brown-button" ng-click="vm.gotoAck()">
          <input type="submit" value="NEXT" class="blue-button" ng-click="vm.checkotp()">
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanx for  "ng-if creates its own scope". :-)

Comment: Your answer also solves the problem by using objects. When we use objects the binding will happen directly to the parent scope.

Comment: Yeah i know but "ng-if creates a child scope" is new to me. and you exaplained well why the code in the question did not worked.

Answer (score 1):

**Make all ng-models of the Form from one Object.**.

It would work and there are other advantages for this like you could easily reset and post data with just one object.:-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
$scope.formData = {};
  $scope.renderotpform = true;
  $scope.checkotp = function() {
    console.log($scope.formData.otp);
  }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <form name="otpform" novalidate ng-if="renderotpform">
      <fieldset ng-disabled="otpdisable">
        <div class="middle-container steps fourth-step overflow-hidden" id="divotp">
          <input class="" type="text" name="otp"  ng-model="formData.otp" required>
          <input type="button" value="BACK" class="brown-button" ng-click="gotoAck()">
          <input type="submit" value="NEXT" class="blue-button" ng-click="checkotp()">
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
```