# AngularJS $http get text

Tags: angularjs, http

I need to get a text from file `text.log`, Here's my code :

```
  vm.logget = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: 'text.log'
        })
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                $scope.logget = response;
                console.log($scope.logget);

            }, function errorCallback(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('error');
            });

    }
```

text.log :

```
creating: /asd/ds/das/das-dsss/
creating: /asd/ds/das/das-dsss/
creating: /asd/ds/das/das-dsss/
creating: /asd/ds/das/das-dsss/
creating: /asd/ds/das/das-dsss/
```

PLunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/g1t4pludTTIAJYKTToCK?p=preview

I don't get anything in succesCallback.
Thanks for answers in advance!

Comment: you are missing controller as syntax in your plunker `ng-controller="FirstCtrl as vm"`

Comment: also u are using `logget` twice; one for function and another for variable. Please refer my answer

Comment: Using logget twice will work since one is defined on vm and another on $scope. But still it is better to use different varaibles in order to avoid any future discrepancy@Rahul

Comment: @vivz absolutely correct; however if you are following controller as syntax then its better to not mess up with `$scope` unless its actually needed

Answer (score 1):

use `ng-controller="FirstCtrl as vm"` or change the function to

```
$scope.logget = function() {
   $http({
       method: 'Get',
       url: 'text.log'
     })
     .then(function successCallback(response) {
       $scope.data = response;
       console.log($scope.data);

     }, function errorCallback(response) {
       console.log(response);
       console.log('error');
     });
}
```

Working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/jhntJ3fnc6K1coWr8aPZ?p=preview)

Comment: you are reassigning `$scope.logget` in `$http` response again.

Comment: fixed it @Rahul.

Answer (score 1):

Please try following code in your plunker:
in HTML :

```
 <body ng-controller="FirstCtrl as vm">
      <button ng-click="vm.logget();" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Log</button>
          {{vm.loggetData}} <!--See I have changed the Binding variable-->
 </body>
```

and in Controller :

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);
app.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
     var vm = this;
     vm.logget = function(){
        $http({
            method: 'Get',
            url: 'text.log'
        }).then(function(response) {
               vm.loggetData = response.data;
             }, function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                console.log('error');
            });
      }

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in your code

First you have to use controller as syntax

`ng-controller="FirstCtrl as vm"`

Second you have to access the data property of your response

```
 vm.logget1 = response.data;
```

**Working Plunker**: http://plnkr.co/edit/cqhzeb4dJoyr7BSP2LAA?p=preview

**Note**: It is better if you use a different variable for storing your response since logget is already your function name. And also try to avoid `$scope` if you are using controller as syntax

**For more Info on controller as**:  [AngularJs "controller as" syntax - clarification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21287794/angularjs-controller-as-syntax-clarification)